# Facing issues in react-navigation

Tags: android, react-native

Well am tring to importing react-navigation but it show me an error can anyone solve my problem

here is my code

npm install react-navigation --save

error is :

[Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-navigaton - Not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EJg2.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this code because of the latest version of `react-navigation`

```
//For React Navigation 4+   
npm install @react-navigation/native
```